Issue with Deserializing a Custom Transformer Model in TensorFlow
I'm encountering an issue when trying to deserialize a custom Transformer model in TensorFlow.And therefore I cannot save and load my model like this :  model_directory ="saved_model.keras" transformer_model.save(model_directory) load_transformer_model = load_model("saved_model.keras", custom_objects=custom_objects)
The error message I'm receiving is:
TypeError: <class '__main__.Transformer'> could not be deserialized properly. Please ensure that components that are Python object instances (layers, models, etc.) returned by `get_config()` are explicitly deserialized in the model's `from_config()` method.

config={'module': None, 'class_name': 'Transformer', 'config': {'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32'}, 'registered_name': 'Custom>Transformer', 'build_config': {'input_shape': [1, 10]}}.

Exception encountered: Unable to revive model from config. When overriding the `get_config()` method, make sure that the returned config contains all items used as arguments in the constructor to <class '__main__.Transformer'>, which is the default behavior. You can override this default behavior by defining a `from_config(cls, config)` class method to specify how to create an instance of Transformer from its config.

Received config={'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32'}

Error encountered during deserialization: Transformer.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'trainable'


Here's a code snippet of my Transformer Class (I have the following classes: Transformer, Encoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer), Decoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer), EncoderLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer), DecoderLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer)):
class Transformer(tf.keras.Model):
    """
    The Transformer model architecture, consisting of an Encoder and Decoder.
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        num_layers,
        d_model,
        num_heads,
        d_feedforward,
        input_vocab_size,
        target_vocab_size,
        max_num_positions_in_pe_encoder,
        max_num_positions_in_pe_decoder,
        dropout_rate=0.1
        #**kwargs,
     ):
        """
        Parameters:
            num_layers (int): Number of layers in both Encoder and Decoder.
            d_model (int): Dimension of the model.
            num_heads (int): Number of attention heads.
            d_feedforward (int): Dimension of the feed forward network.
            input_vocab_size (int): Size of the input vocabulary.
            target_vocab_size (int): Size of the target vocabulary.
            max_num_positions_in_pe_encoder (int): The maximum positions for input.
            max_num_positions_in_pe_decoder (int): The maximum positions for
                target.
            dropout_rate (float): Dropout dropout_rate.
        """
        super(Transformer, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = Encoder(
            num_layers=num_layers,
            d_model=d_model,
            num_heads=num_heads,
            d_feedforward=d_feedforward,
            input_vocab_size=input_vocab_size,
            maximum_positions_in_pe=max_num_positions_in_pe_encoder,
            dropout_rate=dropout_rate,
        )
        self.decoder = Decoder(
            num_layers=num_layers,
            d_model=d_model,
            num_heads=num_heads,
            d_feedforward=d_feedforward,
            target_vocab_size=target_vocab_size,
            maximum_positions_in_pe=max_num_positions_in_pe_decoder,
            dropout_rate=dropout_rate,
        )
        self.final_layer = Dense(target_vocab_size)

Configuration:
TensorFlow version: 2.16.1
Python version: 3.10.12

What I've Tried:
I've tried to implement/override a get_config(), from_config(), build_from_config() method for my Transformer class, then for each of my classes. but I get this kind of mistakes
I've attempted to use the custom_objects when loading.

Here's an example of one the get_config() method I tried to implement for my Transformer class:
# def get_config(self):
    #     config = {
    #         'num_layers': self.num_layers,
    #         'd_model': self.d_model,
    #         'num_heads': self.num_heads,
    #         'd_feedforward': self.d_feedforward,
    #         'input_vocab_size': self.input_vocab_size,
    #         'target_vocab_size': self.target_vocab_size,
    #         'max_num_positions_in_pe_encoder': self.max_num_positions_in_pe_encoder,
    #         'max_num_positions_in_pe_decoder': self.max_num_positions_in_pe_decoder,
    #         'dropout_rate': self.dropout_rate,
    #     }
    #     return config

But I still get this
KeyError: 'num_layers'

Expected Outcome:
I would like to be able to save and load my model properly model without encountering any errors. Any guidance or suggestions on how to properly handle the save and load/deserialization process would be greatly appreciated.
